# Can I disable button text antialiasing

Tags: android

I use custom 8bit font and I'm looking for a way to disable antialias.

I tried the code behind, but It doesn't work:

```xml
<!-- main_activity.xml -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Button" />

<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:antialias">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#0099cc</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">4</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.01</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to disable `antialiasing` using `xml`, but you can try to disable it programmatically `button.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);`

Comment: Thanks, It works. Please write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to disable `antialiasing` using `xml`, but you can try to disable it programmatically `button.getPaint().setAntiAlias(false);`